# Matlab: How to construct a series of constants? And How to reuse them?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of constants

```
case 'a'
  h_grad = 300;h_alpha = 0.11;
case 'b'
  h_grad = 350;h_alpha = 0.15;
case 'c'
  h_grad = 450;h_alpha = 0.22;
case 'd'
  h_grad = 550;h_alpha = 0.3;
```

How can I construct them, so I can use them like `a.h_grad`, `a.h_alpha`, or `b.h_grad`, `b.h_alph`. ?

And I may want to use these data like:

```
v = custom_function(a)
% surface_type could be a, b, c or d
  function v = custom_function(surface_type)
    h_grad = surface_type.h_grad;
    h_alpha = surface_type.h_alpha;
    v = h_grad^h_alpha
  end
```

And, since a/b/c/d may be used in other cases for other variable, how can I put these predefined a.h_grad constant into another object? So they wont pollute the who program.
For example, I may re-use them like `My_Constant_Containter.a.h_grad`?

Comment: Yes, `My_Constant_Containter` would be a good solution. In case of that you can keep the original order of the structure field names `a.h_grad` and can refer to types as `My_Constant_Containter.(surface_type).h_grad`, see my edited answer.

Comment: Let me ask you - How do you plan to use such a three-level deep struct? Maybe you are making it too complicated? What if you could store it as `My_Constant_Containter(1).h_grad`, `My_Constant_Containter(2).h_grad`, `My_Constant_Containter(3).h_grad` and `My_Constant_Containter(4).h_grad` and similarly for `h_alpha`? Having a field just to store a scalar seems inefficient to me.

Comment: @Divakar. Well, that was simply a suggestion, on the other hand I have quite complex codes where array of structures and structure of arrays are nested (even up to level 8) and forming hierarchy in a logical manner (at least for me). My experience is that such structuring of parameters makes it much easier to remember and to use them. I am talking about hundreds of variables with different meaning, it would be a nightmare to lump them into a matrix. For this problem it is probably unnecessary, but for large codes I think clarity is more important.

Comment: @Arpi For storing scalars, it makes sense to have a struct of arrays rather, right? Of course, you would be loosing the fieldnames there, so I guess if that's important, then having different fieldnames could be preferred. By the way, my earlier comment question was directed at asker.

Comment: @Divakar Ok, I forgot for a moment that the asker suggested the three-level structure :). Regarding structure of arrays, it depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
a.h_grad = 300;a.h_alpha = 0.11;
b.h_grad = 350;b.h_alpha = 0.15;
c.h_grad = 450;c.h_alpha = 0.22;
d.h_grad = 550;d.h_alpha = 0.3;
```

They are called [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html) type variables.
The `case` words are not clear to me, are you using [`switch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)?

**EDIT:**
Based on the new info you provided, one possibility if you want to keep the structure variables (CC-constant container):

```
CC.a.h_grad = 300;CC.a.h_alpha = 0.11;
CC.b.h_grad = 350;CC.b.h_alpha = 0.15;
CC.c.h_grad = 450;CC.c.h_alpha = 0.22;
CC.d.h_grad = 550;CC.d.h_alpha = 0.3;

surface_type = 'b';

function v = custom_function(surface_type)
    h_grad_i  = CC.(surface_type).h_grad;
    h_alpha_i = CC.(surface_type).h_alpha;
    v         = h_grad_i^h_alpha_i;
end
```

Comment: That's great. Can we make the defining code more beautiful? There're too many `cc` and a/b/c/d there. I thought about using Object-Oriented in Matlab, But don't know how.

Comment: BTW I like your solution! +1, could have been easier if OP had cleared out those important stuffs at the start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`deal`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)** (`Distribute inputs to outputs`) here -

```
%// Define arrays to hold the scalars
h_grad_vals = [300 350 450 550];  
h_alpha_vals = [0.11 0.15 0.22 0.3];

h1 = num2cell(h_grad_vals)
[a.h_grad,b.h_grad,c.h_grad,d.h_grad] = deal(h1{:})

h2 = num2cell(h_alpha_vals)
[a.h_alpha,b.h_alpha,c.h_alpha,d.h_alpha] = deal(h2{:})
```

Output -

```
a = 
     h_grad: 300
    h_alpha: 0.1100
b = 
     h_grad: 350
    h_alpha: 0.1500
c = 
     h_grad: 450
    h_alpha: 0.2200
d = 
     h_grad: 550
    h_alpha: 0.3000
```

---

### Suggestion

Rather than saving to four different structs, for easy portability of codes and code maintenance, it would make more sense to have these scalars stored as struct of arrays. So, you can do this -

```
A.h_grad = h_grad_vals %// h_grad_vals from earlier code
A.h_alpha = h_alpha_vals %// h_alpha_vals from earlier code
```

Thus, you would be get -

```
A = 
     h_grad: [300 350 450 550]
    h_alpha: [0.1100 0.1500 0.2200 0.3000]
```

Leaving you with just one variable `A` and thus, a much cleaner workspace!

---

### Edit

Here's a fix to solve the question based on the new info provided in the *Edit* section -

```
A = cat(1,a,b,c,d);
fns = {'a','b','c','d'};
for k = 1:numel(fns)
    My_Constant_Containter.(char(fns(k))) = A(k);
end
```

Here's the data store in the output struct looks like -

```
>> My_Constant_Containter.a
ans = 
     h_grad: 300
    h_alpha: 0.1100
>> My_Constant_Containter.b
ans = 
     h_grad: 350
    h_alpha: 0.1500
>> My_Constant_Containter.c
ans = 
     h_grad: 450
    h_alpha: 0.2200
>> My_Constant_Containter.d
ans = 
     h_grad: 550
    h_alpha: 0.3000
```

Comment: Well... The real issue is that I have a/b/c/d four different set of data to use. See My update.

Comment: @cqcn1991 Check out the **Edit**  section to solve the question based on the new requirements?

Comment: My fault. I didn't realize the real issue at first. Ther first `My_Container` is about pollute. The `a./b.` is the identifier for re-use the data. And in my case, I need to select which set of data to use depending on it.

Comment: @cqcn1991 So it's still not working? Could you update the question with what you mean by the `identifier` thing?